# Instantiate Entity Framework controller from class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using Entity Framework code-first to create a few endpoints in a .net core project.

I have another class and will like to use one of the method in the entity class controller without making an API call since they are both in the same project but I am not sure what to use for the context.

**NoteController**:

```
[Route("api/note")]
public class NoteController : Controller
{
    private readonly HDDbContext _context;

    public NoteController(HDDbContext  context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("{userid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetNote([FromRoute] int userid)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var note= await _context.Note.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserId == userid);

        if (note== null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(note);
    }
}
```

**USENOTE** class:

Is it possible to use the controller methods in a class?

```
public class USENOTE 
{
     NoteController  nc = new NoteController().GetNote(1) //Not sure if this is possible
}
```

Comment: This is bad practice. I would move whatever `GetNote` does into a separate, injectable service and use it in both `NoteController` and `USENOTE` (but don't use names like that for classes).

Comment: Well this is breaking the pattern... I think there are fishy ways to do what you ask but I would not recommend. Why do you need to do this? there might be some other/better ways.

Comment: How are you creating your `USENOTE` class? Just inject that into your controller the same way as you do the context.

Comment: @DavidG  thanks i will look up youtube view on how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that it's a bad idea. Here's an example of what you could do.

**NotesRepository.cs**

In this case, I've refactored the get-note-by-id logic into a class as follows:

```
public class NotesRepository
{
    private readonly HDDbContext _context;
    public NotesRepository(HDDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task<Note> GetNoteAsync(int id)
    {
        // your logic
        return note;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

Registered it with the DI container to make it accessible everywhere:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... the existing code

    // Register the notes repository as a service
    services.AddScoped<NotesRepository>();
}
```

You can now use it from as many controllers/services as you want using DI:

```
public class NoteController : Controller
{
    private readonly NotesRepository _notes;

    public NoteController(NotesRepository  notes)
    {
        _notes = notes;
    }

    [HttpGet("{userid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetNote([FromRoute] int userid)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var note = await _notes.GetAsync(userId);

        if (note == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(note);
    }
}
```